# How can I create a prisma relation for a Member model that has a father, mother and children properties?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, database-design, orm, prisma

It's supposed to bea User's information object, where I can see the user's family members. And thus I want to self-reference for the father, mother and children props.

I've tried something like this:

```
model Member {
  id String @id @default(uuid())
  father    Member?  @relation("ParentChildren", fields: [fatherId], references: [id])
  fatherId  String?
  mother    Member?  @relation("ParentChildren", fields: [motherId], references: [id])
  motherId  String?
  children  Member[] @relation("ParentChildren")
  partner   Member
}
```

But apparently we can only have two relations of the same kind.
The idea behind it is to be able to do the follow: When user A adds a parent B, then user A should automatically be added to user B children. And if there's a partner, then it should also be added to their children.

Do I need an extra table to handle this? Or how do you do that?